# how to fix "jwtMiddleware.Handler undefined" when using JWT?

Tags: go, jwt

I met a problem when using `jwt-middleware` in my go project.
The error log is shown as follows:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:101:54: undefined: jwtmiddleware.Options
./main.go:108:34: jwtMiddleware.Handler undefined (type *jwtmiddleware.JWTMiddleware has no field or method Handler)
./main.go:109:36: jwtMiddleware.Handler undefined (type *jwtmiddleware.JWTMiddleware has no field or method Handler)
```

And the related code is shown as follows:

```
var jwtMiddleware = jwtmiddleware.New(jwtmiddleware.Options{
        ValidationKeyGetter: func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            return mySigningKey, nil
        },
        SigningMethod: jwt.SigningMethodHS256,
    })

    r.Handle("/post", jwtMiddleware.Handler(http.HandlerFunc(handlerPost))).Methods("POST")
    r.Handle("/search", jwtMiddleware.Handler(http.HandlerFunc(handlerSearch))).Methods("GET")
    r.Handle("/login", http.HandlerFunc(loginHandler)).Methods("POST")
    r.Handle("/signup", http.HandlerFunc(signupHandler)).Methods("POST")
```

I imported as follows:

```
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"

    jwtmiddleware "github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/pborman/uuid"
    elastic "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v3"
)
```

And I have go get the related libraries:

```
go get "github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware"
```

Is there anyone knowing how to fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answering. But it didn't work in my machine. And I check the package I imported and found that in the auto0 packet there aren't .go file called Handler.go and Options.go. I think that is the main reason. And I search in github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware repository, I still can not find that file.@Jictyvoo

Comment: Check your capitalisation, imports need to be capitalised, and the same throughout. It looks like your code has jwtmiddleware.thing and it's imported as jwtMiddleware, try being consistent throughout with JwtMiddleware and JwtMiddleware.thing

Comment: Thank you for your replying but it still doesn't. I am also very confused

Answer (score 0):

I tested your snippet here and it works well with package import

```
package test

import (
    jwtmiddleware "github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware"
    "github.com/form3tech-oss/jwt-go"
)

var jwtMiddleware = jwtmiddleware.New(jwtmiddleware.Options{
    ValidationKeyGetter: func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return "mySigningKey", nil
    },
    SigningMethod: jwt.SigningMethodHS256,
})
```

Try to run `go mod tidy` and/or `go mod download`, to ensure that the packages are downloaded. In case this even don't work, try `go mod vendor`, this last command will download all needed packages in a folder named `vendor`. If it yet don't work, check the package you are importing inside the `vendor` folder

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answering. But it didn't work in my machine. And I check the package I imported and found that in the auto0 packet there aren't .go file called Handler.go and Options.go. I think that is the main reason. And I search in github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware repository, I still can not find that file.

Comment: You need to make sure which version of the package you are using, as I tested here, the version of the package that you code tried to use is the version 1.0.1; But this package already has the version 2.0.1, which doesn't contains any neither **Options** and **Handler** struct/functions. So, try to define correctly the package version in your `go.mod` file

Comment: Also, post your `go.mod` file, so we can understand better the error